# How to set scrolling performance for webview?

Tags: android, performance, webview, scroll

I load url, for example mail.google.com, into webview in my app, and scrolling on web-page so slow! Tested on Samsung GalaxyTab 10.1, Motorola Droid X, Acer Liquid, etc.
Why?

Parameters that I try use:
`webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I am having similar issues.

Comment: Are you saying it's slower than if you'd load it into the standard browser? Or are you just not satisfied with the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to the  tag in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Remove background image of the webview if you put it and also see if you used heavy size images in progress or loading or other images of heavy size reduce their sizes or remove it

Answer (score -2):

This is a main.xml file

This code is a scrolling only, any where u can use

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">  
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
 android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="This is a header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:paddingLeft="8dip"
          android:paddingRight="8dip"
           android:paddingTop="8dip"></TextView>  
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02"
     android:id="@+id/TextView02"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"></TextView>  

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"></Button>  
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button02"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"></Button>  
 </LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>  





</ScrollView>
```

This is .java file

```
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class ScrollViewActivity extends Activity {  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);  
    String s="";  
    for (int i=0; i < 200; i++) {  
        s += "Android Market ";  
    }  
    view.setText(s);  
}  
}
```

Comment: He is asking about the WebView, not ScrollView!